# Cycles Material Ignoring Transparency Shader

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials

Currently, I have an HDR lit scene with a tree. The tree has a particle system for leaves, that distribute them along the weight painted branches. This works perfectly fine except for the material I have on the leaves, I have a alpha map of a leaf to literally just make it a solid color, and a transparency shader to remove the rest from view. I even made the color bit an emission shader to remove the lighting part of the problem, but the inside bits where the leaves come together are still pitch black. What can I do to fix it?

Pictures: (The UV maps in the pictures are unrelated to the leaves)
[image: Overview]
[image: Close Up]